Looking for creative solutions for an undetectable leak in ceiling
I'll try to keep this summary as short as possible. I bought and moved into a townhouse just over a year ago. About 5 months after moving in, i began to notice some water spots in my bedroom ceiling. I had a contractor make a hole in my ceiling last January to try to detect the source of the leak, but there was no trace at the time. A bit of additional context, a part of my bedroom is below a balcony. As well, since the hole was made in my ceiling back in January, it has leaked only 4-5 times, and the amount of water it leaks is not enough to fill a cup. It appears to only leak during heavy, long rainstorms (so a lot of rain for a long time). After doing some water tests, we are 99% sure the leak is coming from somewhere on the balcony, but we are unable to identify the direct cause. I've had two contractors, a general inspector, a roofer, and a masonry expert come check it out and none are unable to definitively figure out where the water is coming from. I have re-done all the caulking around my place and my balcony, i have added some flashers as well to try to direct the water away from certain areas of the balcony. Hasn't fixed the problem. I am mentally and emotionally drained from this issue. The experts said the amount of intervention needed to definitely trace the source of the leak would be excessive, expensive, and not recommended given the frequency/severity of the leak (talking about removing entire brick walls, tearing apart floorboards, etc).
Given the amount of work/money that would be required to figure this out, and the low frequency/severity of the leak, i am starting to wonder if i should change my approach on this. Given the extreme difficulty in identifying the source of the leak, i'm wondering if i should shift to defense and look for creative ways to prevent this leak from causing more headaches. Rather than preventing the leak, look for ways to prevent the small about of water finding it's way through from causing issues. For example, i still have a large hole in my bedroom that i would love to patch up. Is there any way i could patch it up with a material (rather than drywall) that is more absorbent/protective to a little bit of water so it doesn't cause water spots in the ceiling (i recognize the mold risk here, i will need to figure out a solution to that too). Is there something i could place on my ceiling below the balcony to seal it better to prevent the water from dripping down at all? (this is going to sound so dumb, but like flex seal). Is there some kind of coating i could spray or place on the bricks in my balcony to prevent water from seeping through?
I am open and appreciative to all your suggestions.

damp spots can be distant from the water source.  especially if the ceiling is on Rondo® channel and the drips fall in.

An inspection camera(for smart phone) could be bought and used during a heavy rain.  It should at least see where the water is coming from.

Water can also travel along structure, and the location where the leak is may not be above where the water ends up.

I would focus on the ledger where the balcony is attached. Since your ceiling is already open have 1 person spray a hose on the ledger at different angles while another person watches inside. Give it a couple of minutes as it sounds like the leak is small. It's never a good idea to let water in and hope that it gets absorbed before it hits the ceiling.

This is what we have done multiple times. It is incredibly difficult to isolate where the water is infiltrating from. It also can take up to 10 minutes to see the water trickle through.

@Mark I've tracked leaks this way too. It takes extreme patience. One must mentally divide the outdoor surface into zones and wet the lowest and nearest zone first, waiting plenty of time for water to make its appearance, before moving on to wet the next zone. If possible, arrange the work so that the wetting of the subsequent zones does not also wet the previously-tested zones. In a particularly difficult scenario like yours it could make sense to wet only one or two zones in session, then wait for it to dry before doing more.

Keep in mind that exterior walls are designed with drainage planes: water that gets behind the cladding very high on the wall should reach the house wrap layer and easily drain to the bottom of the wall, where a flashing should direct it out of the wall assembly. It may be that your wrap layer is somehow defective, perhaps around an outlet, door, or window penetration, and water gets to the wrong side of the wrap and enters the building.
